# Steam opening games in background when using controller

Tags: steam, controllers, windows, steam-input

This is only happening when playing with a controller. It appears as though gamepad commands are going out of the game and triggering things in Windows.

This happens with Steam Big Picture and the Desktop client.

Steam Input is enabled:
[image]

My thinking is this has to do with some recent Windows change. I haven't played games in 3 months, so I'm wondering if a recent Windows or Steam update changed this behavior.

```
Steam Version:  1689034492
Steam Client Build Date:  Mon, Jul 10 8:02 PM UTC -08:00
Steam Web Build Date:  Mon, Jul 10 12:48 PM UTC -08:00
Steam API Version:  SteamClient020
```

I also have the regular non-beta client installed:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking your desktop layout? It's right under "Xbox Extended Feature Support Driver".

Comment: Seems to be fixed now as of the latest update some time ago.